# Problems adding interactivity in d3.js Maps [dropdown menu]

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet, maps

I want to produce maps as an output for quantitative analysis.
I Have multiple variables to add to my map, and, I dont want to have n-output, in this case, n-maps. You can have a look of the simplified dataframe *(colomns are years, but it could also be a set of different variables)* :
[Simple data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcHp9.png)

It seems to me d3.js was a good idea, because it can display 1 map with a dropdown menu, and the user can select the variable.

I have produced a map with d3.js before, and I use it as template. I have made it quiet basic and simple (really small dataset, etc), you can found it here in this repo GitHub :
https://github.com/Mathiaslauber/Without_interactivity

Here is the Github repo with my first try of implementing interactivity
[https://github.com/Mathiaslauber/Interactivity_first_try](https://github.com/Mathiaslauber/geovis_qualite_vie_suisse)
Or if you prefer, I have just made a FiddleJS to make things easier : [Fiddle JS Interacivity first try](https://jsfiddle.net/MathiasLauber/hu39nco7/18/)

It was part of a bigger project, you can have a look if you want. [GithubPages](https://github.com/Mathiaslauber/geovis_qualite_vie_suisse)

So far, I have made deseperates modifications that remain unsucessful, because examples are usually very diffrent in many aspects, so hardly reproductible for me. I'm quiet new AND bad with function implemantation in JavaScript.
The two following links are examples that did not seem that complicated and inspired me :

[A] http://tietyk.github.io/D3/Prototype/part9-9.html

[B] http://bl.ocks.org/rgdonohue/6a30b731230f6e242a54

I have interesting bunch of codes at lines 196-226 below, also in the js file.
Problem is I'm missing clues to make it work.

First one used come from source [A] and it's based on an hover effect.
Second, from source [B] and used button
Both refered to json properties, and I use Csv. The overall format and function implementation is different.

I could spend like a month trying to figure this out myself. So if you have any hints, It would help me a lot : Things i should check, that are missing in my code, etc.

```js
 // 2 bunch of codes that were used in order to add interactivity     

    /*        
       color();
               
       d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function() {
           attribute = this.id;
           color();
       });

       function color(){
           
           d3.selectAll('circle')
               .transition()
               .attr( "fill", function(d){
                   return (mycolor.domain())}  
                           )
       }
       
       */
    /*  
        var timeline = d3.selectAll(".time-series")
        .on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
          year = i;
          svg.selectAll("path")
            .attr("class", quantify);
          d3.selectAll(".time-series")
            .attr("class", "time-series");
          this.className = "time-series active";
        });
    */
```

Comment: Do you want the colors to change according to the chosen radio option (x2010, x2011, x2012)? If yes, I forked your fiddle with some changes. https://jsfiddle.net/70u1ejvf/1/

Comment: ^Changes: converted the `citiesOverlay` into a function that accepts the chosen radio value as an argument. Every time you change the radio option, the previous overlay is removed and the new one is added to the map. (Also added values to the radio inputs to make this work)

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you're trying to do with the `timeline`.

Comment: It's an intersting solution you've added. I think it works fine for what I need. THANK YOU Just to make sure :   

 1. I need to put names of the columns (of the csv file) in <input type="radio" name="well" id="x2012" **value="x2012"**  /><label for="x2012">x2012</label>       </form>
It's mandatory to put x2012 in the field value ?

Comment: 2. I have never seen anywhere d3.select**('#well-form')**.on('change', function(e,d) { I assume it is related to the mention in hmtl : <input type="radio" **name="well"**id="x2012" value="x2012" /><label for="x2012">x2012</label> </form> Do we agree that this name "well" could totally something else ?

Comment: 1. What you have inside the value attribute is completely up to you, but that's what you will get when the user changes the chosen radio input in the change event 2. Yes, `well` can be something else. Note that I have added the id `well-form` to the form that wraps your radio inputs.